# How do I know if a vector function (SIMD) really worked on multiple objects at a time?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, parallel-processing, intel, simd

I am trying to understand whether my compiler interprets my vector notation as single objects (equivalent to a for loop) or works on multiple data at a time.

Does anyone know how I do it? I have Intel Parallel Studio 2011 installed on Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in doubt look at the generated code, e.g.

```
$ icc -S ... foo.c -o foo.S
```

Comment: Where can I find it? How can I learn from it about what actually happened? I realize this it is a lot to ask, maybe you could refer me to a place where I can read about it? Thank you :)

Comment: Just open up the generated .S file and look at the code - if you're not familiar with x86 instructions then you can get documentation in PDF form from intel.com.

Comment: just found out: if working with visual studio one can add a breakpoint , run the debugger and then right click to see the disassembler code.

Comment: @N.M.: yes, that also works, but you generally get more symbolic information with compiler-generated asm or even disassembled object files.